# How to compute a md5 hash in a pre-request script in PostMan?

Tags: javascript, hash, md5, postman

I have to set a parameter in my request that is a md5 hash of two other parameters. I think a pre-request script can do the job, but I do not know how to compute a md5 in this script. Any idea?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can create the following pre-request script provided your parameters are defined environment variables. You would need to tweak this example if they are defined in some other fashion.

```js
// Access your env variables like this
var str_1 = environment.variable_1 + environment.variable_2;

// Or get your request parameters
var str_2 = request.data["foo"] + request.data["bar"];

// Use the CryptoJS
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(str_1 + str_2).toString();

// Set the new environment variable
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('hash', hash);
```

CryptoJS works because it's available in Postman (as well as lodash, backbone etc).

Accessing environment variables is easy through the `environment` object.

Setting environment variables is available through the `postman` object.

After this pre-request has run you can access the `hash` variable using the normal `{{hash}}` shorthand.

Also, you can read  [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox) about libraries, variables and properties available in Postman.

Answer (score -3):

FYI, since Postman 4.6.0+ you can no longer include external libraries with $.getScript calls and promise returns, as jQuery was depreciated in favour of [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) from 4.6.0.

Therefore if you wish to include a third party library in your pre-request scripts, at present the only way to do so is storing the contents of the file in a environment variable and running eval() in your sript - [see why here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180).

For example:

```
eval(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("JSSHA"));
```

There are however some libraries included with Postman that do not require this workaround, these are [listed here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/sandbox).